# Facebook Photo Sharing Within App

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I have created a photo frame using HTML5 Canvas and surrounded the canvas with a div tag to add a photo-frame like image. This use will drag and drop the image inside the canvas within the   photo frame. Now the hard part is how do they share that? the photo frame and image inside the canvas via facebook, twitter and facebook. Do I create an extra frame surrounding the photo frame and canvas? what do I do? please help!

Here's the [link to the app](http://on.fb.me/1b6GUj6)

and here's my code

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
tests = {
  filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
  dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
  formdata: !!window.FormData,
  progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
}, 
support = {
  filereader: document.getElementById('filereader'),
  formdata: document.getElementById('formdata'),
  progress: document.getElementById('progress')
},
acceptedTypes = {
  'image/png': true,
  'image/jpeg': true,
  'image/gif': true
},
progress = document.getElementById('uploadprogress'),
fileupload = document.getElementById('upload');
```

Comment: You can not share any custom HTML design elements. If you want your user’s photo to be shared with the surrounding design elements, then you have to _include_ them in the image that you share on Facebook – s that means generating the image dynamically.

Comment: How do I do that? anything would help please

Comment: Depends on what techniques you have available. Server-side with PHP you could use the image functions of the GDlib, for example.

Comment: can you please show me an example link?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+dynamically+generate+image+php